# the datetime inserted is one hour late in database

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I am creating a NextJs app using Prisma, when i post the data containing the datetime value to the api, the datetime inserted is **one hour late** in the MySQL database. I tried sending it as a string using **toLocaleString()** and then converting it to a new Date object in the api but it throws an error. Finally, I have tried **toISOString()** but the date is still one hour late in the DB.

The client code :

```js
axios
    .post('/api/reservations', {
            ...values,
            date: values.date.dateTime?.toISOString()
    })
```

In the api:

```js
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();

    const { nom, prenom, email, tel, espace, nbre, date, nuit } = body;

    const reservation = await prisma.reservation.create({
        data: {
            nom,
            prenom,
            email,
            tel,
            espace,
            nbre,
            dateTime: new Date(date),
            nuit
        }
    });

    return NextResponse.json(reservation);
}
```

The datetime value on the console is :

```js
Sun Jul 16 2023 16:00:00 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)
```

Comment: You are 1 hour ahead of UTC. Is the date in the database in UTC?

Comment: It's a MySQL database, using phpmyadmin. How can I check ?

Comment: Not sure, mySql not my field. But I assume somewhere you have access to a UI/client where you can query the database? In which case do that. However beware the UIs may auto-convert things like dates to locale-specific times.

Comment: Buy default all datetime is stored on database with utc time. when you query database it again convert to your timezone before returning data.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case - mySql stores UTC dates. So you need to be aware of that and the impact it might have on how you insert dates and read them back for use/display. There looks to be a lot online about this already.

Comment: You can check timezone by using -  `<?php echo date_default_timezone_get(); ?>`

Comment: How can I adapt mysql to store the correct datetime??

Comment: It looks like it is storing the *correct* datetime. If it (and you!) assume all DB date/times are UTC then you know exactly what time it is and can adjust those date/times by various offsets for locale-specific time. Any issue would seem to be with your application - you need to be aware the mySql will store UTC and adjust your app as required. As I said, there seems to be a lot about this online so I suggest you look into it a bit more.